# Split field values using specific character by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry for the repeated question. I already asked for help about this by the use of ORACLE database. But now I really wanted to know how can I split this using MySQL database

It is possible to split field values using a specific character? Here is my sample table

```
value
10uF
2K
1.0uF
200UF
```

I want it to split by this:

```
 value       capacitance/resistance
 10            uF
 2             K
 1.0           uF
 200           UF
```

Hope you can help me once again. Thanks! and more power!

Comment: I'm guessing the second value should really be "2K".

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
create table temp
(value varchar(10)
 );

insert into temp values ('10uF');
insert into temp values('2K');

SELECT value + 0 AS num
     , REPLACE(value,value+0,'') AS unit
  FROM temp

O/P

num letter
10  uF
2   K
```

The trick the query is using is to evaluate the column value in a numeric context, by adding a zero. MySQL will return the numeric value.

But this wont work in case of 10Uf10,2k3..

Hope all your data is digit + charachter

[Fiddle for the same](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e9e4/2)

Comment: thanks for the answer it worked! :) But one thing I want to know, what if my data have a special character like "?"

Comment: @MyrtsGC "?" come after digit or in between digit?

Comment: o/p will be num=0 and letter = ?

Comment: and also what if my data have a "/" special character, between the digit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MyrtsGrc if any charachter come in between the digit this will not work.

Comment: can you give me a code that will work to be able to split it like this, 1/4W separated by 1/4  W . 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @MyrtsGrc the capacitance/resistance are fixed values always? if so pls tell what are the possible values for that